# Nativescript app crashes on adding nativescript-admob plugin

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin, firebase-admob

I'm trying to add ads in my ng-nativescript app using **nativescript-admob** plugin.I'm following
[this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/11/google-admob-nativescript-angular-2/) guide.I've done everything right but my app is crashing everytime.
here is *app.component.ts*
`

```
private androidBannerId: string = "ca-app-pub-kkkkkkkkk/tttttt";//replaced my own id
      public createBanner() {
          Admob.createBanner({
              testing: true,
              size: Admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER,
              androidBannerId: this.androidBannerId,
              margins: {
                  bottom: 0
              }
          }).then(function() {
              console.log("admob createBanner done");
          }, function(error) {
              console.log("admob createBanner error: " + error);
          });
      }
    
      public hideBanner() {
          Admob.hideBanner().then(function() {
              console.log("admob hideBanner done");
          }, function(error) {
              console.log("admob hideBanner error: " + error);
          });
      }
```

`
I've updated AndroidManifest.xml as mentioned in guide post.also I'm using nativescript-firebase
plugin by eddy verbruggen.Please help me here.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I found out, that just installing the plugin is enough to crash the emulator. I haven't changed my functioning code, only thing I did was `tns plugin add nativescript-admob` And app started crashing right away.

Comment: @ndrjvvr use AdMob features in the Firebase plugin instead of nativescript-admob if you r using firebase plugin .